# Tracking clients in a WCF wsDualHttpBinding Context

Tags: c#, wcf, wcf-binding

I use wsDualHttpBinding in a wcf service, and i use the following code to store client channels:

```
    public static void Subscribe()
    {
        try
        {
            // Subscribe the guest to the beer inventory
            var guest = OperationContext.Current.GetCallbackChannel<ILoggingServiceCallBack>();

            if (!CallbackList.Contains(guest))
            {
                CallbackList.Add(guest);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            //do stuff
        }
        finally
        {
           //do stuff
        }

    }
```

and i call back clients like that:

```
        public static void LoggingCallBack(Action<ILoggingServiceCallBack> callbackNotification)
    {
        try
        {
            if (OperationContext.Current != null)
            {
                var guest = OperationContext.Current.GetCallbackChannel<ILoggingServiceCallBack>();
                if (!CallbackList.Contains(guest))
                {
                    CallbackList.Add(guest);
                }
            }

            foreach (var LoggingCallBack in CallbackList)
            {

       var temp = LoggingCallBack;
                try
                {
                    new Thread(() =>
                    {
                        try
                        {
                            callbackNotification(temp);
                        }
                        catch (Exception ex)
                        {
                            //do something
                        }
                    }).Start();


                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    //do somethin
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            //doing something
        }
        finally
        {
         //doing something
        }
    }
```

im running through some troubles:

1. i have no way to tell if the client is online or not before i call
   it back.
2. i need to be able to remove the client after no activity from the
   list i guess i would be able to do that if i achieved number 1.
3. what is the best way to identify clients, in other words what is
   the best unique identifier i can identify the client with?
4. if a connection with the client faulted i don't know how to detect
   that and start new one from the client as if i tried to do that it refuse to and it throw exception that the connection is faulted.

sorry if i have asked more than one question, please give your opinion about the code i posted and any answer to any question of the above.

Comment: Point 4 is awfully tricky business!

Comment: The easiest way is simply catch exceptions if anything goes wrong and open a new connection.